Absolute path failing on compilation
I have a nx repository with a single project and various libs
in my main file I do
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { router } from 'src/+routes';


  const app = express();
  const server = http.createServer(app);

  // Middleware
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use(router);

  app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`[ ready ] http://${host}:${port}`);
  });




I have various folder under
/root
  |
  |- /src
      |-/+controller
      |-/+routes
      |-/+models
      main.ts

so my main ts is using absolute import and should call the index file in +routes folder.
From vs code, all looks good and there is no issue.
the problem when I build I have

Error: Cannot find module 'src/+routes'
Require stack:


C:\Users\us\Repository\Project\dist\app\src+config\express.config.js
C:\Users\us\Repository\Project\dist\app\src+config\index.js
C:\Users\us\Repository\Project\dist\app\src\main.js
C:\Users\us\Repository\Project\dist\app\main.js

My tsconfig as this setup
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json",
      "composite": true
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json",
      "composite": true
    }
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}


Somehow it doesnt work. IEven removing paths will still allow me to auto import src/+route but it never work. What is badly configured ?

This is occurring because you are importing from 'src/+routes', which is by default the compiler thinks that you want to import it from the modules folder. in order to solve it you need to change it to this in order to import it from the src folder:
import { router } from './+routes';



Yes, this would work, but then if I want to import /src/+controller with absolute import from somewhere deep inside the src/ folder, I would have to do ../../../../+controller which is not what I aiming for. I guess I need to find why src/+route is autosuggested by vscode, and how to make it work like by doing maybe ~src/+route

cause I try to rename the import in tsconfig and the app to ~src/* but it doesnt the same complaint

you can use the @ sign. so the import will be '@/src/+controller'
